# Bash: Set theory

Tags: bash, awk, set-theory

I have the following tab-delimited table:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
ZO1     X1  X2  X3          X4      X5  X6
ZO2 X7  X8  X9  X10     X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
ZO3 X16 X17 X18 X19         X20     X21 X22
ZO4     X23 X24 X25         X26     X27 X28
ZO5     X29 X30                         
ZO6     X31 X32 X33 X34 X35 X36 X37 X38 X39
ZO7 X40 X41 X42 X43 X44 X45 X46 X47 X48 X49
ZO8     X50 X51 X52         X53     X54 X55
```

(X## is a random string)

And I want to extract the values in column #1, that fulfill a certain condition. An exemplary condition would be: Retrieve all values (column1), that have a non-empty value in the columns B,C,D,G,I,J and empty values in the remaining columns A,E,F,H.

So an example output would be:

```
Z01
Z04
Z08
```

EDIT: Sorry for the poor input. Below a semicolon-delimited table; the real input is TAB-delimited

```
;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J
ZO1;;X1;X2;X3;;;X4;;X5;X6
ZO2;X7;X8;X9;X10;;X11;X12;X13;X14;X15
ZO3;X16;X17;X18;X19;;;X20;;X21;X22
ZO4;;X23;X24;X25;;;X26;;X27;X28
ZO5;;X29;X30;;;;;;;
ZO6;;X31;X32;X33;X34;X35;X36;X37;X38;X39
ZO7;X40;X41;X42;X43;X44;X45;X46;X47;X48;X49
ZO8;;X50;X51;X52;;;X53;;X54;X55
```

Comment: Put in the proper entabbed example.

Comment: Put semicolons or something else we can see/use instead of tabs in your example and then we'll have something we can test against and so will be able to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton but my example is tab-delimited, how should I then give a realistic input?

Comment: Your real input is separated by a single character, a tab. Your posted sample input is not separated by a single character and cannot be separated by tabs on this site therefore you cannot post "realistic" input o nthis site and therefore need to compromise. It is far more useful to post, say, comma-separated input and simply state "in my real file the commas are tabs" than post input separated by multiple blanks (which require a different tool) so we have input that's separated by a single char to test against and can make any necessary accommodations/statements to the real input being tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this one, It'll run if you copy and paste it whole into bash, comments and all.

```
tail -n +2 file              `# Grab the bit of the file you car about` \
|  sed 's/;/|;/'           `# Protect the first column`               \
|  sed 's/;[^;][^;]*/1/g' `# Change all the filled values to 1`      \
|  sed 's/;/0/g'            `# Change the empty values to 0`
```

The output of that command looks like this:

```
 ZO1|0111001011
 ZO2|1111011111
 ZO3|1111001011
 ZO4|0111001011
 ZO5|0110000000
 ZO6|0111111111
 ZO7|1111111111
 ZO8|0111001011
```

So now I can set the pattern I'm looking for.

```
tail -n +2 file              `# Grab the bit of the file you car about` \
|  sed 's/;/|;/'           `# Protect the first column`               \
|  sed 's/;[^;][^;]*/1/g' `# Change all the filled values to 1`      \
|  sed 's/;/0/g'            `# Change the empty values to 0`           \
|  grep "|0111001011"        `# Grab the match you want`                \
|  sed  's/|.*//'            `# Clear out the garbage`
```

Then Id g eneralize it with a function

```
>> function table_match () {
    cat                          `# Grab the stdin`                     \
    |  sed 's/;/|;/'           `# Protect the first column`           \
    |  sed 's/;[^;][^;]*/1/g' `# Change all the filled values to 1`  \
    |  sed 's/;/0/g'            `# Change the empty values to 0`       \
    |  grep "|${1}"              `# Grab the match you want`            \
    |  sed  's/|.*//'            `# Clear out the garbage`;
}


>> tail -n +2 file | table_match 0111001011
ZO1
ZO4
ZO8
```

I can do other stuff too ... dot wild card ... kleene star ... nifty.

```
>> tail -n +2 file | table_match .......011
ZO1
ZO2
ZO3
ZO4
ZO5
ZO6
ZO7
ZO8

>> tail -n +2 file | table_match 01*
ZO1 
ZO4 
ZO5 
ZO6 
ZO8
```

Comment: You can combine the first three `sed` substitutions into a single command: `sed -e 'first' -e 'second' -e 'third'`...

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah looks like it. I had to fake an input because i couldn't copy and paste and I had some bad chars.

Comment: strangely, the two lines with replacing the fields with 0/1 does not work

Comment: I wont if the file is not actually tab delimited. Are you sure its tab delimited and not set width spaces ?

Comment: I updated it to work with the semicolon delimited file you gave. Not sure the issue with you tab file.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want something like this:

```
awk -v pres='B,C,D,G,I,J' '
    BEGIN { FS="\t" }
    FNR==1 {
        split(pres,tmp,/,/)
        for (i in tmp) {
            presNames[tmp[i]]
        }
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i in presNames) {
                mustBePresent[i]
            }
        }
        next
    }
    {
        pass = 1
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ( ($i == "") &&  (i in mustBePresent) ) { pass = 0 }
            if ( ($i != "") && !(i in mustBePresent) ) { pass = 0 }
        }
        if (pass) {
            print $1
        }
    }
' file
```

Untested since you didn't provide sample input we could easily copy/paste to test with.

I actually like [@gbtimmon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378927/1745001) of creating bit map of the fields a little better than the above so here's how you'd do that in awk:

```
awk -v pres='B,C,D,G,I,J' '
    BEGIN { FS="\t" }
    FNR==1 {
        split(pres,tmp,/,/)
        for (i in tmp) {
            presNames[tmp[i]]
        }
        req = 1
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            req = req ($i in presNames ? 1 : 0)
        }
        next
    }
    {
        act = 1
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            act = act ($i == "" ? 0 : 1)
        }
        if (act == req) {
            print $1
        }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ printf "\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH\tI\tJ
ZO1\t\tX1\tX2\tX3\t\t\tX4\t\tX5\tX6
ZO2\tX7\tX8\tX9\tX10\t\tX11\tX12\tX13\tX14\tX15
ZO3\tX16\tX17\tX18\tX19\t\t\tX20\t\tX21\tX22
ZO4\t\tX23\tX24\tX25\t\t\tX26\t\tX27\tX28
ZO5\t\tX29\tX30\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
ZO6\t\tX31\tX32\tX33\tX34\tX35\tX36\tX37\tX38\tX39
ZO7\tX40\tX41\tX42\tX43\tX44\tX45\tX46\tX47\tX48\tX49
ZO8\t\tX50\tX51\tX52\t\t\tX53\t\tX54\tX55\n" > file
```

In Ruby:

```
$ sed -E '1 s/^(.*)$/hdr\1/' /tmp/file | 
  ruby -e 'require "csv"
           options={:col_sep=>"\t", :headers=>true}
           CSV.parse($<, options){ |r| 
               puts r["hdr"] if ("B|C|D|G|I|J".split("|").map{ |e| r[e]!=nil }.all? \
                             && "A|E|F|H".split("|").map { |e| r[e]==nil }.all?) } '
ZO1
ZO4
ZO8
```

Or, little less terse:

```
$ sed -E '1 s/^(.*)$/hdr\1/' /tmp/file | 
ruby -e 'require "csv"
         options={:col_sep=>"\t", :headers=>true}
         CSV.parse($<, options)
            .select { |r| "B|C|D|G|I|J".split("|").map{ |e| r[e]!=nil }.all? }
            .select { |r| "A|E|F|H".split("|").map { |e| r[e]==nil }.all? }
            .map { |r| puts r["hdr"] } '
```

Both cases:

1. Use `sed` to insert a `hdr` fields since the header line is one less field that the data below;
2. Use the `CSV` module to read the modified file;
3. Blank fields are assigned `nil` in the CSV module. Use that to select the logic you describe.

---

Using the truth table approach that gbtimmon [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378927/298607), in Ruby:

```
$ sed -E '1 s/^(.*)$/hdr\1/' file |
ruby -e 'require "csv"
        options={:col_sep=>"\t", :headers=>true}
        tt=CSV.parse($<, options)
            .map { |r| [r[0], r[1..-1].map { |e| e==nil ? "0" : "1" }.join ] }
            .group_by { |hdr, bits| bits }
            .map { |bits,lol| [bits, lol.map(&:first)] }.to_h 
        tt.map { |k, a| puts "#{k} => #{a.join(%q(, ))}" if k=~/^./ } '
0111001011 => ZO1, ZO4, ZO8
1111011111 => ZO2
1111001011 => ZO3
0110000000 => ZO5
0111111111 => ZO6
1111111111 => ZO7
```

You can add whatever regex in the regex literal `k=~/^./` to produce the result desired.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS=", " }
      NR==1 { next } 
            { ind=""
              for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)
                 ind=ind ($i=="" ? "0" : "1")
            map[ind]=map[ind] ? map[ind] OFS $1 : $1
            }  
      END   { for( e in map) printf "%s => %s\n", e, map[e] }' file
0111111111 => ZO6
0111001011 => ZO1, ZO4, ZO8
0110000000 => ZO5
1111111111 => ZO7
1111011111 => ZO2
1111001011 => ZO3
```

the table entries will come in an unordered result but then pipe that to `sed` or `grep` to select the row (or part of row) desired (or right inside the `awk` loop at the end).

Best

Comment: this awk solution rules!

Answer (score 0):

A couple simple ways to do this.  Here's a more C like syntax:

```
awk -F'\t' '{if( $2=="" && $3!="" && $4!="" && $5!="" && $6=="" && $7=="" && $8!="" && $9=="" && $10!="" && $11!="" ) print $1}' table_file
```

And another more compressed version in awk native syntax, as suggested by karakfa in comments below:

```
awk -F'\t' '$3!="" && $4!="" && $5!="" && $8!="" && $10!="" && $11!="" && $2$6$7$9 == "" {print $1}' table_file
```

Comment: why has this answer been downvoted? only because of the curly bracket missing?

Comment: @tobi, thanks for spotting the missing bracket!  No idea why it got down voted.  It's not a dynamic solution, but does the job.

Comment: well, the numeration of the columns is wrong, this should work: `awk -F'\t' '{if( $2=="" && $3!="" && $4!="" && $5!="" && $6=="" && $7=="" && $8!="" && $9=="" && $10!="" && $11!="" ) print $1}'`

Comment: you can remove `if` by moving the condition out of the block.  Also you can combine nulls into one `$2$6$7$9==""`

Comment: Showing C-like or Lisp-like ot Prolog-like or anything-else-like syntax isn't useful. It's an awk script so just show awk syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with a "straight" awk solution is the parsing of the space and the fact that awk won't see the empty fields we therefore have to use sed alongside awk.

```
sed -rn 's/([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:blank:]]{4})/,&/gp' filename | sed -rn 's/[[:blank:]]//gp' filename | awk -F , 'NR > 1 { if ( $3 == "" && $4 != "" && $5 != "" && $6 != "" && $7 == "" && $8 == "" && $9 != "" && $10 == "" && $11 != "" && $12 != "" ) { print $2 } }'



sed -rn 's/([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:blank:]]{4})/,&/gp' filename | sed -rn 's/[[:blank:]]//gp' filename
```

First with sed, add a comma before any characters or 4 blank spaces. Then run an second sed statement to remove the blank spaces.

This leaves you with

```
,,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
,ZO1,,X1,X2,X3,,,X4,,X5,X6
,ZO2,X7,X8,X9,X10,,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15
,ZO3,X16,X17,X18,X19,,,X20,,X21,X22
,ZO4,,X23,X24,X25,,,X26,,X27,X28
,ZO5,,X29,X30,,,,,,
,ZO6,,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36,X37,X38,X39
,ZO7,X40,X41,X42,X43,X44,X45,X46,X47,X48,X49
,ZO8,,X50,X51,X52,,,X53,,X54,X55
```

Then use awk to process this data:

```
awk -F , 'NR > 1 { if ( $3 == "" && $4 != "" && $5 != "" && $6 != "" && $7 == "" && $8 == "" && $9 != "" && $10 == "" && $11 != "" && $12 != "" ) { print $2 } }'
```

Use , as the field delimiter and then check the delimited fields against certain conditions.

Output:

```
ZO1
ZO4
ZO8
```